# How to make GoogleAdSense (Custom Search Ads) to be responsive (bootstrap)?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, adsense

We have google ads implemented in our website. 
Recently we changed the entire website to responsive design. So I was looking at options from google and found out that google has an api for responsive design. I looked at ways to implement it.

What I found from documentation and verious examples posted over internet was to get responsive ads using this

```
 <script async src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <div id='GoogleAdParentContainer'>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display: block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxx" data-ad-slot="yyyyyyyy" data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
 </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

I completely understand how the above code works and I tested it and its absolutely fine - **but my problem is we were using custom ads from google where we were passing the search string, etc to query the google ads.** 
We use custom ads with query since our website is very big.
Our script goes like this -

```
    //Our existing code with custom search query to get relevant ads
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
       var pageOptions = { 'pubId': 'pub-id','query': 'toy search in new york'};
       var adblock1 = 
       { 
         'container': 'adcontainer1',
         'number': 4,
         'width': '700px',
         'noTitleUnderline': true 
       };
      _googCsa('ads', pageOptions, adblock1);
    </script>
```

**Now I dont know how to make this responsive** - I could not find any documentation. Please help me with this !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is so simple:

replace ---->>> 'width': '700px'

with    ---->>> 'width': '100%'

enjoy your google csa!!!

woody

Comment: this is what I have also thought of as a last resort :) I was just trying to find out if there is any new api for this from google !

Comment: i also use this solution and work perfectly on my website, Google don't say nothing about this but i think that is implicit... ;-)

sorry for the english !